# How to dynamically render meta tags for social share button on a static site?

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags, prerender, socialshare

I have a static site where users can generate images and content in unlimited combinations. When the user is finished, permalink is generated to allow them to share their creation via Facebook/Twitter/GooglePlus/etc. I want their shared post to contain the user's image and content, but I discovered that the social media bots only parse HTML meta tags from my permalinks, and they do not evaluate any Javascript.

How can I make my user's content appear on the shared social media post? When the permalink is clicked, client side Javascript will evaluate the permalink's query params and render the user's content. I can render the user's content inside HTML meta tags too, which is used by Twitter and FB to populate a post's content, but the bots don't evaluate any javascript, so the meta tags are not rendered.

One possible solution that I have explored is pre-rendering. Perhaps my permalink can be the location of an HTML file on an AWS S3 bucket, which I can create as soon as the user shares their permalink. That HTML file on S3 can have the user-specific meta tags in it, and I can provide that to the social media bots. And when that file is accessed, I can have it redirect to my permalink. Does this seem reasonable? I can report back after trying this out.

Another solution is to use a pre-rendering service, like https://prerender.io/. It seems a bit bulky and black-boxed, but it might be more robust and reliable that my S3 solution above. Any ideas?

I am open to feedback and other solutions, and any suggestions would be great.

---

other relevant info:

This answer seems interesting, which involves activating the Facebook Javascript SDK:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178987/1884158

And I am aware of tools like Twitter's Card Validator and Facebooks Share Debugger, here:
https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
which will be useful for testing any solutions.

And if it helps, my site is a React app that is bundled in HTML/CSS/JS and rendered entirely on the client.

Comment: hello I am facing the exact same issue. I have a static hosted on S3 built in Vue. It has jobs that need to be shared on facebook and linkedin. These shared links must have job name, company name and company logo. I can't get this data injected into meta tags.

Have you solved this issue ?

Comment: @HaseebBurki Other than pre-rendering, or migrating to server-side rendering, I don't think this is possible. I did come up with a hack/workaround, described below, but it has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a proper solution to this problem, but I did come up with a workaround/hack that involves setting up a separate service. Here is the service that I came up with: https://github.com/mapseed/sharing/blob/master/share.js

If our static site is hosted at `example.com`, we can spin up a server running at `sharing.example.com` that accepts requests and will either redirect the request from `sharing.example.com/my/route` to `example.com/my/route`. But if the request has a `user-agent` HTTP header matching a social media crawler, as we are doing [here](https://github.com/mapseed/sharing/blob/master/share.js#L16), then we return an html page containing just the meta tags, as we are doing [here](https://github.com/mapseed/sharing/blob/master/utils.js#L1-L16).

This approach has a couple of restrictions, however:

- The links that we want to share on social media need point to our `sharing.example.com` subdomain. This will make it possible for our service to return an HTML page with the proper meta tags if the request is coming from a social media bot, or otherwise redirect the request to our `example.com` website otherwise.
- In order to generate the content of our meta tags, our shareable links will have to have query params to pass all of the information to populate our meta tags. For example, our shareable link would look like this: `sharing.example.com/post/my-post?title=my-title&desc=my-description`. This means that our shareable links can get quite long. You can see how we extract the information from our query params and inject it into our HTML template with the meta tags here: https://github.com/mapseed/sharing/blob/master/share.js#L18-L27

If these restrictions are acceptable, then this solution works quite well. Note that there is also a downside for SEO, because the links that will be shared are coming from `sharing.example.com`, and not our `example.com` website.

Also, we will have to spin up an extra server to run this service. Although we should be able to migrate this implementation into a serverless architecture, like AWS Lambda.

Comment: This is quite a good solution. However it requires too much work and the cost of spinning up a new server just for this one task will not be welcomed by my client. I tried to implement Lambda functions such that whenever a specific url is accessed we get the id of the resource from the url, pull the data from the api, inject it into the html and return that as a response. I don't have much experience with AWS Lambda and wasn't able to make it work. I am working on another solution right now. I'll let you know if it works, otherwise I might have to do it your way too. Thanks

Comment: Hello. I ended up with pre-rendering HTML files with nothing but the meta tags and a bit of javascript to redirect the user to the correct link.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the exact same issue. Even i have a web app developed in reactjs using typescript. I still have not found a solution to this. Can you please tell me how did you do it? I have also posted a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968603/sharing-on-social-media-the-url-does-not-render-any-meta-data/51044550?noredirect=1#comment89113392_51044550)