# Issue with Sharing URL on LinkedIn in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linkedin-api, react-share

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am developing a React application and facing an issue with sharing a URL on LinkedIn. My application has two main components: `App.jsx` and `Share.jsx`. In `Share.jsx`, I have an anchor tag for sharing a link to LinkedIn. However, when I click the anchor, it redirects me to LinkedIn, but the URL I want to share does not seem to work properly. I am unsure what I might be doing wrong.

Here is the relevant code:

**App.jsx:**

```
import Share from './components/Share';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <h1>Hello React World</h1>
      <Link to="/share">Share</Link>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/share" element={<Share />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Share.jsx***

```
const Share = () => {
  let url = encodeURIComponent("https://superlative-bunny-c61262.netlify.app/share");

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Share Social</h2>
      <a target='_blank' className='c-black' rel="noreferrer" href={`https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=${url}`}>
        Share on LinkedIn
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Share;
```

The URL I am trying to share is https://superlative-bunny-c61262.netlify.app/share. When I click on "Share on LinkedIn", it does redirect to LinkedIn, but the URL is not shared as expected.

I have tried searching for similar issues and solutions but haven't found anything that resolves my problem. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong and how to fix it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Clicking the `Share to LinkedIn` button in your page does work for me. It launches the share article screen with a (rather limited) embed of your page.

Comment: can you plz share a screenshot?

Comment: Here you go: https://i.imgur.com/OAAP1Xz.png

Comment: what could be the issue that i am not seeing the same thing?

Comment: Try adding some [OpenGraph meta tags](https://ogp.me/) in your page head, (you could add them directly to the `index.html` file at the root of your project). Though bear in mind that since you're making an SPA, [you may not be able to generate dynamic metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888431/11200608) for your pages.