# How do I get the base url of the site for twitter:image meta tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following front matter in a markdown file.

```
---
title: "Hello world!"
excerpt: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
coverImage: "/assets/blog/hello-world/cover.png"
date: "2020-03-16T05:35:07.322Z"
author:
  name: Mario
  picture: "/assets/blog/authors/mario.png"
ogImage:
  url: "/assets/blog/hello-world/cover.png"
---
```

I require passing the full url of the image to twitter card meta `twitter: image` and open graph meta `property = "og: image"`

For this I need to obtain the base url of the site to use it as a prefix to the image path that I obtain through front matter

```
<Head>
  {/* Twitter */}
  ...
  <meta name="twitter:image" content={data.ogImage.url} />

  {/* Open Graph */}
  ...
  <meta property="og:url" content={``} key="ogurl" />
  <meta property="og:image" content={data.ogImage.url} key="ogimage" />
</Head>
```

For now `data.ogImage.url` has the value `/assets/blog/hello-world/cover.png` but in order to work I need to prefix this output with site base url

How do I get the base url of the site in nextjs?

Comment: I haven't used nextjs before but can you use vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55151122/615274 helped me understand that I need to use side effect to get the value of `window.location.href` in the page component of nextjs.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to achieve such a thing:

1. **Create your base URL in `env`** file and refer it by `proccess.env` *([This](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables) may help with this approach)*.

   The `.env` file:

   ```
   // .env

   REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://example.com/
   ```

   The `index` file:

   ```html
   <!-- index -->

   <meta property="og:image" content={`${process.env.BASE_URL}${data.ogImage.url}`} key="ogimage" />
   ```
2. **Using a relative path**, in this approach, you should use image relative path which work like this *([this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) may help with it)*:

   Let's say we have below structure:

   ```
   --src
     |--assets
        |--images
           |--image.png
   --index
   ```

   If we are in index file we will refer to that image like this:

   ```html
   <meta property="og:image" content={`./src/${data.ogImage.url}`} key="ogimage" />
                                               |__let's say this will return assets/images/image.png
   ```
3. **Use javascript built-in methods** like `window.location`. To access the base URL we can get `origin` property from it like this: `window.location.origin` *(For using this method in `next.js` [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1553#issuecomment-290062887) may probably help)*.

   ```html
   <meta property="og:image" content={`${window.location.origin}${data.ogImage.url}`} key="ogimage" />
   ```

**NOTE:** As @AlexeiLevenkov mentioned in comments since you are asking for the full path of the image, the best way to do it would sticking with the first approach.

Comment: Note that since question ask "I require passing the full url of the image to twitter card meta twitter: image and open graph meta property = "og: image"" only first option actually related to the question. And it is the only possible option - code that renders web page on server generally has no idea what url it will be exposed at so that value has to be passed in. And since the tags in question are for bots they generally must be rendered server side.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use normal client-side JavaScript (I haven't used nextjs before) you can access the base url of the page with `window.location.origin`

Comment: I am new with nextjs and nodejs, the component is a nextjs page and when trying `window.location.origin` I get the error message window is not defined

Comment: @user615274 is your code running server-side (on Node rather than in the browser)? If so, I am incorrect and you can't use client-side JavaScript

Comment: OP asked about meta tags used by bots... Most of them don't run client side pages and only look at server response - so `window.location` is of no use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The following screenshot explain everything in itself. If you aren't able to access the **window** object then probably you are using at a place where it is actually not accessible. You can try writing your short script in  tag and can update the meta values. In that script, you'd access to the window object.

[image]

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968603/sharing-on-social-media-the-url-does-not-render-any-meta-data and explain how image of `window` object helps in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

During [server side rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) you have no `window`, so you cant get access to `location`.
But you can leave `url` prefix empty on server side and define it on client.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968603/sharing-on-social-media-the-url-does-not-render-any-meta-data and explain how "leave url prefix empty on server side and define it on client" helps in this particular case.

Answer (score -2):

As explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55151122/615274 Using side effect in the component allows me to access the `window` object and in consequence to `window.location.href` the final solution looks similar to this

```
export default function Post({ post, name }) {
  const { data, content } = post;
  const [origin, setOrigin] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOrigin(window.location.origin); // <-- here I get access to window
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout title={data.title} description={data.excerpt}>
      <Head>
        {/* Twitter */}
        <meta name="twitter:image" content={`${origin}${data.ogImage.url}`} />

        {/* Open Graph */}
        <meta property="og:image" content={`${origin}${data.ogImage.url}`} key="ogimage"
        />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <PostBody data={data}>{content}</PostBody>
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

In the content attribute of `twitter:image` and `og:image` I can set the full url like this `` `${origin}${data.ogImage.url}` ``

Comment: This is pointless, as Facebook bot will not render the page and see here an empty value.